# Can't run node express on centos server

Tags: node.js, express, centos, web-deployment

I am trying to run an express app that I installed using `express --view pug urltracker`. I also executed `npm install` to install all dependencies.

When I start it on my laptop localhost using `DEBUG=urltracker:* && npm start`
it perfectly starts on `localhost:3000` and my app runs smoothly but when I install it on centos 7 server, the same gets stuck at `` [nodemon] starting `node ./bin/www `` and nothing happens afterwards.

I tried running it like this as well `DEBUG=backend ./bin/www` but it says `-bash: ./bin/www: Permission denied` OR `sudo: ./bin/www: command not found`

I can execute a normal file like `node app.js` and it works fine but when it comes to running it as server, it doesn't work.

Here's my package.json

```
{
  "name": "urltracker",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.18.2",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "express": "~4.15.5",
    "morgan": "~1.9.0",
    "pug": "2.0.0-beta11",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.4.5",
    "puppeteer": "^1.6.2",
    "puppeteer-select": "^1.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint-plugin-mocha": "^4.11.0",
    "file-system": "^2.2.2",
    "jest": "^21.2.1",
    "js-comments": "^0.5.4",
    "lodash": "^4.17.13"
  }
}
```

I also tried it with running node supervisor using `supervisor ./bin/www`
but it says

```
Starting child process with 'node ./bin/www'
Watching directory '/home/admin/web/example.com/node/projects' for changes.
Press rs for restarting the process.
```

I also tried changing the port to `3001` in ./bin/www like this - `server.listen('3001', '0.0.0.0');`

but nothing works. Help.

Answer (score 0):

Nodemon is not listed in your dependencies list in `package.json` and on the centos server nodemon is not present.

Please add the nodemon dependency in the package.json and then run npm i
or change the start script from `"start": "nodemon ./bin/www"` to `"start": "node ./bin/www"`

Comment: I have installed nodemon globally using npm install -g nodemon
so it is available for me to use, do I still need to add it in package.json?
because the same is done in my laptop localhost and working fine